# Empty pivot table with pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have [checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672506/missing-values-in-pandas-pivot-table) [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431157/python-pandas-pivot-table-missing-column-after-pivot), but it seems I can't find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57548077/pandas-pivot-table-returns-empty-data-frame) (or at least an answer) anywhere.
Say I have this data frame with empty cells

```
data = pd.DataFrame( {'A': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a1', 2: 'a1', 3: 'a1', 4: 'a1', 5: 'a2', 6: 'a2', 7: 'a2', 8: 'a2', 9: 'a2'}, 'B': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: 'bb', 6: 'bc', 7: 'bd', 8: 'be', 9: 'bf'}, 'col': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10, 5: 10, 6: 10, 7: 10, 8: 10, 9: 10}, 'C': {0: 'c1', 1: 'c1', 2: 'c1', 3: 'c1', 4: 'c1', 5: 'c2', 6: 'c2', 7: 'c2', 8: 'c2', 9: 'c2'}, 'D': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 'E': {0: 'e1', 1: 'e2', 2: 'e3', 3: 'e4', 4: 'e5', 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}} )
```

[image]

I'd like to pivot column values, so I'm trying:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(data, values='D', index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'E'], columns=['col'])
```

I'd expect something like

[image]

Instead, I get an empty table. Can anyone help here?

Comment: no images please, always provide a data as a code (preferably) or a text . please refer to SO guidelines   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pivot = pd.pivot(data, values='D', index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'E'], columns=['col'])
```

If you want to reset the index you can use `pivot.reset_index()` which returns:

```
col   A    B   C    E  10
0    a1  NaN  c1   e1   0
1    a1  NaN  c1   e2   0
2    a1  NaN  c1   e3   0
3    a1  NaN  c1   e4   0
4    a1  NaN  c1   e5   0
5    a2   bb  c2  NaN   0
6    a2   bc  c2  NaN   0
7    a2   bd  c2  NaN   0
8    a2   be  c2  NaN   0
9    a2   bf  c2  NaN   0
```